# Type EXTERNAL returned when a Google group is a member of another Google group

Tags: google-admin-sdk

The documentation https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members#resource says that allowed values for a Google Group member type are `CUSTOMER`, `GROUP` or `USER`.

Today, the https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list API returns `type="EXTERNAL"` for members that are other Google Groups of the platform (instead of returning `type="GROUP"`)

```
{
   "kind": "admin#directory#member",
   "etag": "%etag%",
   "id": "%id%",
   "email": "%email%",
   "role": "MEMBER",
   "type": "EXTERNAL",
   "status": "UNKNOWN"
  }
```

Also, the id returned by the API is not the one that was returned in the past (now, it is 21 digits, but before, it was 15 digits and letters).

Has an undocumented change happened in the Directory API ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Google inadvertently allowed this breaking API change to be released to a subset of servers (canaries). We (Okta) also were observing this issue in production since 5am on Monday morning.

We're currently working with Google to resolve this issue and will post updates to https://trust.okta.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google rolled back the change that caused the regression Yesterday afternoon.

However, as of 5AM this morning we (Okta) have started observing this issue in production again. We're currently working with Google to resolve this issue and will post updates to https://trust.okta.com/.